# Extract Salesforce record Id from URL with Zapier Push

Tags: url, salesforce, extract, zapier

I need a way to extract the Salesforce record ID from a URL using Zapier Push. How can I find the first 3 characters in a string that match the start of the Id like 006 and then return a set number of characters after that?

The url is formatted as such:

`https://useindio.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/006f400000AiVufAAF/view`

Comment: It&#39;ll be helpful if you can post some sample data here.

Comment: Sorry about that... This is the URL that pulls in via push

https://useindio.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/006f400000AiVufAAF/view

I want to extract the 18 characters starting at 006 after /Opportunity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Good question!

Whenever you want to extract data from a string and you know the exact format the string will be in, Regular Expressions are the answer.

Assuming you want to grab anything after `006` (and you know it'll always be there), you could use the regex `006(\w{15})` ([more info](https://regex101.com/r/LA4G6o/1/)), which will find the 15 characters after that. If you know the surrounding url will always be the same, you could easily grab the whole ID by anchoring via `Opportunity` and `view`: `\/Opportunity\/(.*)\/view` ([more info](https://regex101.com/r/LA4G6o/2)).

Either way, there's info about setting up a formatter zap [here](https://zapier.com/blog/updates/1305/formatter-regex-support), or you could do it in code ([JS Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), [Python Example](https://regexone.com/references/python)).

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!